# How to prove that $C^N_c (K) = \{{\phi\in C^N(R^N):\operatorname{supp}\phi\subset K}\}$ is a Banach space?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, banach-spaces, compactness, distribution-theory

I am trying to prove the next claim-

Let K be a compact set, and N a nonnegative integer. then
$$C^N_c (K) = \{{\phi\in C^N(R^N):\operatorname{supp}\phi\subset K}\}$$ is a Banach space when it is equipped with the norm
$$\phi \rightarrow \Sigma_{|\alpha|\le N} \sup|\partial^\alpha \phi |$$
Is there any connection to uniform convergence?

Comment: Yes: pointwise convergence implies uniform convergence on a compact set.

Comment: Uniform convergence of a sequence of bounded continuous functions is equivalent to the convergence in the $\sup$ norm, and therefore the fact that that space is Banach follows from the theorem of differentiability of limit with uniformly convergence differentials